# Как можно сделать массив в массиве? c++

Tags: python, c++, массивы

Надо сделать несколько массивов в одном массиве. В качестве примера могу показать как это работает на **Python**:

```
numbers = [[0,1,2],[0,3,6],[3,4,5],[1,4,7],[6,7,8],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
print(numbers[1][1]) #3
```

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать на языке **C++**, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers = {{0,1,2},{0,3,6},{3,4,5},{1,4,7},{6,7,8},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
std::cout << numbers[1][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Объявление двумерного массива: `int a[строки][столбцы];`

Инициализация: `int a[2][3] = {{4, 7, 8}, {9, 6, 5}};`

**Вывод:**

```
4 7 8

9 6 5
```

Comment: Для вывода элементов используйте обращение по индексу:

`cout << a[1][1]`

Comment: Мне выдаёт ошибку в этой строчке "int win_coords[4][2] = {{0,1,2},{0,3,6},{3,4,5},{1,4,7},{6,7,8},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};". Подскажите где ошибка, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Dariuz вы декларируете размер массива как 4 на 2, а инициализируете массивом размером 8 на 3. И текст ошибки желательно указывать (ну и пытаться самостоятельно прочитать ее).

Comment: Понял, спасибо :). Я просто не много по другому представлял как работает двухмерный массив.

Comment: @Dariuz А это не двухмерный массив, это одномерный массив, элементами которого являются другие одномерные массивы.

Comment: @user7860670 Это и называется двумерным массивом

Comment: @nasiA Нет. Например у вас элементы 8 и 9 принадлежат разным объектам, по ним нельзя итерироваться и т.д.

Comment: @user7860670 Про итерацию согласен. Но в плюсах нет объекта для массивов, и единственный способ их создать - сделать одномерные массивы внутри другого одномерного массива. Для простоты их и называют двумерными.